# How to match data in a table from another one?

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet

here's the story.

I'm working on a project where I have several sheets in my Excel document. One sheet for one business.

In each sheet, there is a table like this one:

[image]

I have another sheet where I want to gather the data from all businesses.
Here is the table I have in my "All" sheet:

[image]

I want to find an **Excel function**, or a **combination of several functions** to be able to complete this table using 'Order numbers'. What I mean is that I want the function to look at the order number in the "All" tab and be like:

"Ok, I have this order number **1512**, if I go to the other sheet, I have the same order number, and for this order number, the order type is '**Delivery**', so I return 'Delivery' in cell B2 in the "All" tab."

I hope it is clear, do not hesitate to ask if you want me to explain things a different way.

Same for 'Price' and 'Status'.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `vlookup`? `index/match`?

Comment: I tried both. My problem with VLOOKUP is that I want the function to match exactly what is written in the cells not just the columns. I don't know if you guys understand what I mean. :/

Comment: What would be if you have more that one same order number to other sheets. How many sheets do you have?

Comment: Nope, do not understand.

Comment: A total of 6 sheets, one to gather all the data and 5 others because I have 5 businesses

Answer (score 0):

multiple vlookups shall work with iferrors.

e.g.
below formula to get "Order Type"

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Business1!$A:$D,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Business2!$A:$D,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Business3!$A:$D,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Business4!$A:$D,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Business5!$A:$D,2,0)))))

- Change 5 sheets with your business name (sheetnames)
- for other two variables 'Price' and 'Status', just edit vlookup formula from 2 to 3 & 4 respectively.

Hope it Helps...

Comment: `VSTACK()` can handle this more effectively.

Comment: Yes... VSTACK() does the job... quite new formula in Excel community... Thanks for the update... :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just one more thing, imagine, there is a table for one of my businesses that has only three columns in its table instead of 4 like the other ones. How can I make sure it works?

Comment: You can have one more iferror condition in the end with "NA" (not available), so if one column is not present for any of business then values for those Order Number will get populated with NA...